# How to know the URL that is requesting an image hosted on your server?

Tags: image, algorithm, webserver

I want to start a image hosting company where I charge my users for bandwidth. The image hosting service will let users upload images to my server and use the link on their websites.

The users should also give me the website where they would use these images.

The problem is how can I know if any other website (not authorized by the user) is using these images as well? And probable also suggest some way of stopping other websites from using these images URLs.

Websites of my users can be open and may require no login like blog, e-commerce etc.

Comment: It depends on which server you'll be using, and the programing language you'll use to build your http server modules.

Comment: Can u give an example with some server and some language !

Comment: In IIS, using c#, you can get the url through Request.Url property.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: you could use a webserver like apache, lighty or nginx (...) and use rewrite rules with useful vars like `HTTP_REFERER` to control the access (hotlinking) and activate access_logs. But to serve content fast (like a CDN), you may have to tweak the httpd conf for "serving static content".